# Git: how to show diff of file in working directory after it has been marked "assume-unchanged"? (or skip-worktree)

Tags: git

I know how to use `git update-index --assume-unchanged` on a file in a working directory.

My question is this: Is there any easy way to still check the difference of the file from, say, the version of that pointed to by the HEAD?

Right now I have to temporarily undo `-assume-unchanged` before I can run `git diff`.  The sequence goes like this:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged foo.java
git diff foo.java
git update-index --assume-unchanged foo.java
```

This works but it is kind of clumsy.

The file is tracked by `git` but I need a locally modified version for my development environment.  And I never want to commit the locally mofified version into git.

**Updated**

The question still applies even when I switch to use `skip-worktree` instead
of `assume-unchanged`.  I have just learned that the former option
is a better one if the file is intended to be changed.  See
this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/1168041) for more information about the two options.

Comment: You can run `git diff --no-index` to use `git diff` as a fancier version of plain `diff` ... or just run plain `diff`. But either way you'll have to have a copy of the specific version of the file you want to diff against, such as an extract from the `HEAD` commit, saved somewhere as an ordinary file.

Comment: @torek -- But then it seems the steps are even more clumsy that the sequence that I am using (having to check out a version of the file as an ordinary file somewhere).  Thanks anyway!

Comment: I *think* the correct answer is "use `--skip-worktree`, not `--assume-unchanged`", but I'm not sure. Edit: [it looks like you should be doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree) whether or not it actually helps with `git diff` in particular.

Comment: @Daniel H -- Thanks for the note.  I agree with your comment after reading this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525

Comment: @leeyuiwah Does that also help with `git diff`, or do you still need a solution to that?

Comment: @Daniel H -- The question still applies even if switch to use `--skip-worktree`.  I updated my question above.  Thanks!

Comment: With ordinary diff you can script it somewhat: `git cat-file -p HEAD:path | diff -U - path`. Git's diff seems to require two paths arguments (based on documentation), though if you have `/dev/stdin` you could use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Thanks for all the discussion.  I am answering my own question here.)

It seems that there are no easier solution.  However, by using alias
I can cut down a bit on the typing.

Here are my git aliases:

```
[alias]
        # show only files that have been skip-worktree
        lsfswt = !git ls-files -v | grep "^S"
        uiswt = update-index --skip-worktree
        uinswt = update-index --no-skip-worktree
```

With those aliases, here are what I need to type:

```
git uinswt foo.java
git diff foo.java
git unswt foo.java
```

Answer (score 1):

This will accomplish what you're trying to do.  For a file named `Foo.java`:

```
git show HEAD:Foo.java | git diff --no-index Foo.java -
```

How does it work?  `git show <rev>:<path>` spits out the contents of the file, as they exist in the object database (see [gitrevisions(7)](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememmasterREADMEem)).  Using this, calling regular `diff` with [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) is a viable solution, as in `diff Foo.java <(git show HEAD:Foo.java)`, assuming you're using a shell environment that supports process substitution.  (I've used this when comparing patches.)

You cannot, however, replace this usage of `diff` with `git diff --no-index` to get all the color and word features of `git diff`, as the Git maintainers are very firm about not allowing process substitution with `--no-index`.  (The diff algorithm tries to hash the file contents first, and this is not possible if the file contents are being streamed.)  However, `--no-index` does allow the second file to be standard input (as a special concession to Unix tradition, I suppose), using the special name `-`.

Thus, you show the file's contents with `git show @:Foo.java` and pipe it into `git diff --no-index`, naming the file in the work tree and a dash indicating stdin.

The same trick will work for (npx) `prettier` (see [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier)), which sends the prettified code to standard output if not editing in place.  I was able to use `npx prettier file.js | git diff --no-index file.js -` to highlight the exact line the linter was complaining about.  (See [this comment](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/6885#issuecomment-1112720197) and those it references for the source of this idea.)